# Issue with control group UI?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I need the control group of 100% so that on any type of mobile screen it should fill full screen. I have given the css property but it doesn't working, my code is as follows,

```
  <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a href="#" id="SMS" data-role="button" onClick='goToSms()'>SMS</a>
  <a href="#" id="EMAIL" data-role="button" onClick='gomail()'>Send Email</a>
  <a href="#" id="Save" data-role="button" onClick='goToSave()'>Save Location</a>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .ui-controlgroup-controls {width: 100% !important;}
            #SMS {width:33% !important;}
            #EMAIL {width:33% !important;}
            #Save {width:34% !important;}
```

For the above code I'm getting like this,[image]

I need it in same line and need to fit for all mobile screens

Comment: use a [navbar](http://api.jquerymobile.com/widgets/navbar) or [grid](http://api.jquerymobile.com/grid-layout/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use the horizontal controlgroup, you just need to add the CSS box-sizing: border-box; to the controls so that the 33% includes all borders, margins, etc.:

```
.boxsizing{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="boxsizing">
    <a href="#" id="SMS" data-role="button" onClick='goToSms()' class="boxsizing">SMS</a>
    <a href="#" id="EMAIL" data-role="button" onClick='gomail()' class="boxsizing">Send Email</a>
    <a href="#" id="Save" data-role="button" onClick='goToSave()' class="boxsizing">Save Location</a>
</div>
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/33ax8/)**

However, as user frequent pointed out, the **[NAVBAR](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/navbar/)** widget might be a better choice...